# Set sorting direction for a function that sorts arrays in an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, closures

I have the following array:

```
$data = array(
    array("firstname" => "Mary", "lastname" => "Johnson", "age" => 25),
    array("firstname" => "Amanda", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 18),
    array("firstname" => "James", "lastname" => "Brown", "age" => 31),
    array("firstname" => "Patricia", "lastname" => "Williams", "age" => 7),
    array("firstname" => "Michael", "lastname" => "Davis", "age" => 43),
    array("firstname" => "Sarah", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 24),
    array("firstname" => "Patrick", "lastname" => "Miller", "age" => 27)
);
```

And the following sorting function:

```
function sortArray($data, $field)
  {
    if(!is_array($field)) $field = array($field);
      usort($data, function($a, $b) use($field) {
      $retval = 0;
      foreach($field as $fieldname) {
        if($retval == 0) $retval = strnatcmp($a[$fieldname],$b[$fieldname]);
      }
      return $retval;
    });
    return $data;
  }
```

It works great but I would like to know how can I change it in order to pass a third argument, sort direction (ASC or DESC).

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try? It should be as simple as adding the third argument to the function declaration, then adding some code to use array_reverse or similar.

Comment: This would seem to be fairly trivial. Have you tried this and are running into problems?  Can you show what you tried to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 additions to your code could fix this:

```
function sortArray($data, $field, $dir = "asc")
{
   //All your sorting code
   //Then:
   return strtolower($dir) == "asc" ? $data: array_reverse($data);
}
```

This simply reverses the array and returns it that way when anything is passed to the third parameter that isn't "asc". strtolower() allows you to accept any case ("asc", "ASC", "Asc" etc) so you don't have to remember, and it defaults to ASC which is what one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could create a wrapper for your sorting function:

```
asc_sorter = function(a, b) {
    return arraySorter(a, b);
}

desc_sorter = function(a, b) {
    return -arraySorter(a, b);
}
```

And then call either asc_ or desc_ sorter

Answer (score 0):

You can take in an optional boolean for sorting in descending order and have it default to `false`. Then it's just a matter of multiplying `retval` by `-1` if descending is `true`:

```
function sortArray($data, $field, $descending = false)
  {
    if(!is_array($field)) $field = array($field);
      usort($data, function($a, $b) use($field) {
      $retval = 0;
      foreach($field as $fieldname) {
        if($retval == 0) $retval = strnatcmp($a[$fieldname],$b[$fieldname]);
      }
      return ($descending ? -1 : 1)*$retval;
    });
    return $data;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just reverse the array depending on direction param like so:

```
 function sortArray($data, $field, $direction)
        /* sorting code */

        if($direction == 'DESC')
          return array_reverse($sorted_array);
        else 
          return $sorted_array;
      }
```